# Forwarding traffic to other container

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

I have a `lancachenet/monolithic` container on a server which is responsible for caching Windows Updates.
I would also like to cache Steam and Blizzard games, however, Blizzard especially requires you to have more that 1 server in your DNS record in order to speed up downloads as right now download speed would not go above 8MB/s.

What i was thinking to do is to create a couple of containers on the fixed IP addresses which will simply pass all 80 and 443 requests to the main `lancachenet/monolithic` container, basically they will act as a dumb passthrough routers.

Problem is, i was not been able to find any relevant information on how to do that on the internet, except for [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/833666/forward-traffic-into-docker-container-vm?newreg=d7d04ede9e164142b066bf0a6e781971) serverfault answer.

**Here is my setup:**

1. **DNS Server** - 192.168.2.200
2. **LanCache Monolithic** - 192.168.2.201

**And here is what i was thinking to do:**
3. **Pass-through Container #1** - 192.168.2.202
4. **Pass-through Container #2** - 192.168.2.203
5. **Pass-through Container #3** - 192.168.2.204
6. **Pass-through Container #4** - 192.168.2.205

**Logic is pretty simple:**

1. Steam Client @ 192.168.2.x starts to download game
2. It queries the server @ 192.169.2.200
3. Server tells the client that there are 5 addresses which are resolved to the queried FQDN
4. Steam uses all 5
5. 192.168.2.202/203/204/205 are simply passing through data to 192.168.2.201 and then getting the response back and sending it to Steam to work with

After that, i will be able to update DNS Server with the IP addresses of the *Pass-through* containers, which will trick Steam/Blizzard into thinking that there are multiple connection points available, however, all the traffic will be essentially routed through one container `192.168.2.201` as the *Pass-through* containers are just passing traffic to it.

Can someone point help me with the minimal working example of such container. Simple `Dockerfile` (preferably based on the alpine:latest) or even a link to an existing docker hub page.

**P.S.** I am running the whole setup on the Unraid server 6.8.3, so maybe there are some Unraid specific tricks someone can share to achieve the desired goal.

`lancachenet/monolithic` container settings
[image]

`lancachenet/lancache-dns` container settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at traefik? - https://docs.traefik.io/

Very powerful, and easy to setup in docker and will be able to accomplish what you are looking for.

However - by default docker listens on all IPs on the server - so just adding multiple IP's to the server should also work if I understand what you're looking to do properly.

Comment: I already have Traefik, but it is not what I am actually looking for. I need some sort of Traefik for internal network with "just pass-through" functionality.